# Photoshop redraw issue in JSX modal window when adding dynamic text fields

Tags: photoshop, jsx, extendscript, redraw

I'm having a terrible time trying to get my Photoshop modal dialog to properly redraw the window after adding text fields on the fly in Windows.

There's no issue on Mac, but on Windows the fields look mangled and will not show what is being typed into them.

I've tried various refresh/redraw methods, but nothing seems to work...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Screen shot of fields on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tXRt.png)

[Screen shot of fields on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vqT7.png)

Here is a very simplified version of my script:

```js
#target photoshop

var dlg = new Window('dialog', 'Dynamic Fields Test');

dlg.populateBtn = dlg.add('button', undefined, 'Add fields', {name:'ok'});
dlg.closeBtn = dlg.add('button', undefined, 'Close', {name:'cancel'});

// Create a panel to hold fields group
dlg.dynamicPanel = dlg.add('panel', undefined, "Dynamic Fields:");
dlg.dynamicPanel.orientation = 'column';
dlg.dynamicPanel.alignChildren = 'left';

// Create group to add fields to
dlg.dynamicPanel.fields = dlg.dynamicPanel.add('group', undefined, undefined);
dlg.dynamicPanel.fields.orientation = 'column';

dlg.populateBtn.onClick = function() { dlg.close(); }

dlg.populateBtn.onClick = function()
{
    try
    {
        // Create 10 dynamic edit text fields
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dlg.dynamicPanel.fields[i] = dlg.dynamicPanel.fields.add('group', undefined, undefined);
            dlg.dynamicPanel.fields[i].orientation = 'row';
            
            dlg.dynamicPanel.fields[i].title = dlg.dynamicPanel.fields[i].add('statictext', undefined, 'Dynamic field' + i);
            dlg.dynamicPanel.fields[i].textField = dlg.dynamicPanel.fields[i].add('edittext {text:"", characters:10, justify:"left"}');
        }

        // Try our best to refresh the window
        dlg.layout.layout(true);
    } catch(e) {
        $.writeln(e + " - line: " + e.line);
    }
}

dlg.center();
dlg.show();
```

Comment: I noticed this seems to be a redraw bug in Photoshop CC 2015. I just tested the same script in CC 2017 and it looks fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the same Windows bug I've seen which comes from parenting. Try getting rid of the panel (maybe you can just use some lines in the interface as a workaround) and generate non-parented edittext fields (for which you'll need to re-calculate the coordinates, of course).

Comment: By the way, sorry for the late reply. Also, I have been amazed that this long-standing bug (we're talking YEARS) has never been addressed by Adobe (though I am mostly speaking from experience in After Effects, and perhaps, as you point out, this bug has finally been fixed in the latest CC code).